# Added collection of images from SQL datareader on ItextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I need to get a collection of images from a datareader or even from a datatable (if recommended to use this) of sql.

My intent is to populate the cell with the variable "myimage" (and I succeed perfectly)

In the variable "myimage2" I would like to insert the collection of images obtained from a datareader or a datatable, what can I do?
Currently I can insert only one image using the "getvalue" method as written in the code.

```
Dim connessione As New SqlConnection
Dim comando As New SqlCommand
connessione.ConnectionString = stringa_database
connessione.Open()
comando = connessione.CreateCommand()
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text
comando.CommandText = "SELECT u.id_nota, u.immagine From immagini_aggiuntive u INNER JOIN note q ON q.id = id_nota where id_nota= " & id
Dim lettura As SqlDataReader = comando.ExecuteReader()
lettura.Read()
Dim imageByte2 As Byte() = CType(lettura.GetValue(1), Byte())
Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(imageByte2, 0, imageByte2.Length)
Dim myImage2 As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms2)


'fine blocco

Dim imageByte As Byte() = CType(row.Cells(11).Value, Byte())
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length)
Dim myImage As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms)

Dim cellimg As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell()
cellimg.AddElement(myImage)
cellimg.AddElement(myImage2)
pdfTable.AddCell(cellimg)

lettura.Close()
connessione.Close()
```

Comment: Do you mean that your query returns more than one image record? And you want to populate the cell with all the images returned by the query?

Comment: yes, I would like to obtain the result you proposed

Comment: And what is _row.Cells(11).Value_ ? This seems to be a line of code that copies from some source you have already loaded somewhere.

Comment: Yes exactly. I'll explain:
I have a table "Tab1" with id, date, image, etc ...
I have a second table "Tab2" with id, id_tab1, image
When exporting, I first insert the image present in "Tab1", and then I would like to add the collection of images present in "Tab2"